# UpdatePanel quits responding after Response.TransmitFile

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have a GridView in an UpdatePanel that shows a list of files. One of the columns in the GridView is a button that opens the listed PDF file.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upPurchaseOrder">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvPurachaseOrder" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="odsPurchaseOrders"
            EnableModelValidation="True" DataKeyNames="PurchaseOrderID,PromotionID"  onrowcreated="gvPurachaseOrder_RowCreated">
            <Columns>
                <%--BoundFields omitted--%>
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnPurchaseOrderOpen" runat="server" Text="Open" CommandName="Open" 
                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FilePath") %>' oncommand="btnPurchaseOrderOpen_Command" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the RowCreated event I register btnPurchaseOrderOpen as a PostBack control, so it causes a full postback.

In the button event handler, I open the file with the Response.TransmitFile method.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = GetConentTypeForFile(fi.Extension);
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", fi.Name));
Response.TransmitFile(fi.FullName);
Response.End();
```

My problem is that after the file is opened (it opens correctly) the UpdatePanel stops updating. I can click the other buttons and they never post back synchronously or asynchronously. I have a feeling the problem is related to the response, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a full post back but you are not returning any new page to the server since you are only doing transmitfile and then response.end. It's basically a dead end for your page. The way you may want to get around this is to do the full post back in an iframe or simply create a direct link to the download file, even if that might be a ashx handler where you can continue to have similar logic to what you are already using.